# JSON-RPC method not found. code:-32601

Tags: polkadot

env：parity/polkadot:v0.9.22

```
network: polkadot
  p2pPort: 30333
  validator: false
  syncMode: fast
  pruning: true
  retainedBlocks: 1024
  logging: info
  telemetry: false
  telemetryURL: wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/0
  prometheus: true
  prometheusPort: 9615
  rpc: true
  rpcPort: 9933
  rpcMethods: unsafe
  ws: true
  wsPort: 9944
  corsDomains:
    - '*'
  resources:
    cpu: "4"
    cpuLimit: "8"
    memory: 4Gi
    memoryLimit: 8Gi
    storage: 80Gi
    storageClass: gp2
```

execute code:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"id":1, "jsonrpc":"2.0", "method": "net_peerCount", "params":[]}' http://localhost:9933
```

error:

```
{"code":-32601,"message":"Method not found"}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This rpc is in [frontier](https://github.com/paritytech/frontier/blob/master/client/rpc-core/src/net.rs), not substrate. If you want this rpc, plz add frontier to your node, follow this [guide](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/v3/frontier/) to integrate frontier.

Comment: I want to get the peercount on the Polkadot blockchain The following methods can meet my needs for the time being：

Start adding running parameters --rpc-method=Unsafe
Use system_peers json-rpc method.